# sprite animation individual framerate

Tags: graphics, sprites, graphics-programming, spritesheet, graphic-effects

When animating sprites I am taking the delta difference between frames and locking the rendering frame rate of the sprite animation to the delta time.

```
float delay = 1000.0f / FPS;
float now = SDL_GetTicks();
if(now - sprite->last_update > delay) {
    render sprite frame
}
```

This is causing flickering because the background is being drawn faster than the sprite. (my guess) If I draw as fast as the frame rate the flickering goes away. If I slow down the background rendering then the background flickers. By slow down I mean set the FPS to 30.  I want to be able to slow down the animation for a single sprite.
 I need a better way to lock the frame rate for individual sprites.  I can slow the entire frame rate down by delaying in the game loop but I want to be able to slow down a single sprite.  Is this possible?

Comment: You should draw the sprite every frame. The If check you have will be to advance the frame index.

Comment: @Tetrad brilliant.....that makes sense and it also works...thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how you are already using SDL, I would advice taking the tutorials over at SDLtutorials.

In particular there is a tutorial on Animation which gives you an Animation CLASS, which includes framerate, frame increments, and even other more complex things like oscillation.

http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-animation